# Dependency injection with glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection

I have a folder called core with two files inside: index.js and module.js. I'm kidding a little with dependency injection and ES6, and I would like to receive feedback with improvements for my code.

**index.js**

```
module.exports = [
  {
     mod: require('./module'),
     inj: ['bluebird']
  }
];
```

Inside module:

```
module.exports = function (Promise) {};
```

I want to inject the bluebird lib inside my module.js, so I created this piece of code:

```
 glob(path.resolve() + '/core/index.js', (error, paths) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    for (let file of paths) {
      let index = require(file);

      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(index) !== '[object Array]') {
        return 'Required path is not an array.'
      }

      for (let options of index) {
        options.mod.apply(options.mod, options.inj.map((mod) => {
          try {
            return require(mod);
          } catch (e) {
            return require(path.resolve() + '/core/' + mod);
          }
        }));
      }
    }
  });
```

The idea here is to get the index.js and call the module.js with the bluebird library as the first parameter.

It works just fine, but the code is a mess, and I don't know how to use ES6 yet.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem I see here is why is some other code doing dependency injection for you? Node.js already has dependency injection, why go through all the hoops and do it yourself?

`module.js` could have been as simple as the following, and it would have done the same thing:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function(){
  ...
}
```

Now you might say "Oh, glob is for dynamically adding modules and deps" - erm... no. Your array is no different from doing the following wherever you're callong `glob`, just not in array form and if they just required their own dependencies.

```
require('./module');
require('./another-module');
// and so on...
```